# JBoss 7 multiple log4j Configuration Using Spring Profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, log4j, jboss7.x

Oh the production environment can we start the JBoss7.1.1 AS with standalone.sh ?
Usually we start it with init script, and then deploy the WAR with the help of jboss-cli.sh .
But this method is not letting the logging files create.

```
log4j.appender.A1.File=../server/default/log/Mylog.log
```

When i start the server with standalone.sh the log files are created successfully.

But when i start it with service jboss start & then deploy it with jboss-cli.sh
I get this error.

```
12:00:38,996 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
    12:00:38,997 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../server/default/log/Mylog.log (No such file or directory)
    12:00:38,998 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    12:00:38,998 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    12:00:38,999 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:136)
    12:00:38,999 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    12:00:39,000 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    12:00:39,000 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    12:00:39,000 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    12:00:39,000 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    12:00:39,001 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    12:00:39,001 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    12:00:39,001 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    12:00:39,002 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    12:00:39,002 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    12:00:39,002 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    12:00:39,003 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
    12:00:39,003 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:72)
    12:00:39,003 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    12:00:39,004 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    12:00:39,004 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    12:00:39,004 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    12:00:39,005 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    12:00:39,005 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.doInvok
```

I have added jboss deployment structure also

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jboss-deployment-structure>
        <deployment>
            <exclusions>
                <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            </exclusions>
        </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
    <!-- <jboss-deployment-structure> <deployment> <exclusions> <module name="org.apache.log4j" 
        /> </exclusions> </deployment> <sub-deployment name="takaful.war"> <exclusions> 
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" /> </exclusions> </sub-deployment> <sub-deployment 
        name="takaful-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"> <exclusions> <module name="org.apache.log4j" 
        /> </exclusions> </sub-deployment> </jboss-deployment-structure> -->
```

And last my spring bean to initialize log4j.

```
<beans profile="a">
    <bean id="logb"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
        <list>
        <value>${loc}/${log4j.properties.location}</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        </bean>
        </beans>

        <beans profile="b">
        <bean id="logb"
                        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
        <list>
        <value>${loc}/${log4j.properties.location2}</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        </bean>
        </beans>

        <beans profile="c">
        <bean id="logb"
                        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
        <list>
        <value>${loc}/${log4j.properties.location3}</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        </bean>
        </beans>
```

This code works perfectly if i start JBoss7.1.1.FINAL with standalone.sh  but gives this error if i use service jboss start and deploy war with jboss-cli.sh by deploy warname.war

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It says

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../server/default/log/Mylog.log
```

So the current directory is different when you start with "service jboss start". Try to add JBOSS_HOME to your jboss-as.conf or install JBoss in
JBOSS_HOME=/usr/share/jboss-as